# PHP/PDO: How to add more session data in PHP

Tags: php, session

from the question above, currently I already create a login page. in the login page, I include 'email' as a session and I can borrow the 'email in all page'. Let say if I want to include other data to the session, for example, 'fullname', how to do?

Below is my login code

```
<?php
    include("config/configPDO.php");
    session_start();

    $msg = ""; 
    if(isset($_POST['submitBtnLogin'])) {
    $user_id = trim($_POST['email']);
    $email=explode('@',$user_id);
    if (is_array($email)){
        $user_id=$email[0];
    }
    $pwd = trim($_POST['pwd']);
    if($user_id != "" && $pwd != "") {

        $ldap_dn = "TOPGLOVE\\".$user_id;
        $ldap_password = $pwd;

        $ldap_con = ldap_connect("ldap://172.xx.xx.xx:xxx");
        ldap_set_option($ldap_con, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);

        if(@ldap_bind($ldap_con,$ldap_dn,$ldap_password)){;
            try {

                $records = $conn->prepare("SELECT email, roles_id, pwd FROM users WHERE user_id = :user_id ");
                $records->execute(
                    array(  
                    'user_id'     =>    $user_id,
                    )  
                );
                $results = $records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                $message = '';

                if($results && count($results) > 0 ){
                    $_SESSION['login_user'] = $results["email"];
                    if($results["roles_id"] == "1"){ 
                        header("location: pages/dashboard/dashboard_admin.php");
                    }else if ($results["roles_id"] == "3"){ 
                        header("location: pages/dashboard/dashboard_super_admin.php");
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "
                    <script>alert('You're not authorized to use this system')</script>
                    <script>window.location = 'index.php'</script>
                    ";
                }

            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                echo "Error : ".$e->getMessage();
            }
        } else{ 
        echo "
        <script>alert('Invalid Email or Password')</script>
        <script>window.location = 'index.php'</script>
        ";
        }

    } else {
        $msg = "Both fields are required!";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Just add it as another element in `$_SESSION` e.g. `$_SESSION['fullname'] = $fullname;`. Or I am not getting the question?

Comment: From the docs: _$_SESSION is an associative array containing session variables available to the current script_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Nick said, make sure the SESSION is started and the User has been logged in.

Then you can use $_SESSION Array, to add new elements.

```
$_SESSION['name'] = $your_var;
```